# Error in FF - c[Db] is not a function

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to use Google Maps on my site. I use this code

```
 <script type="text/javascript"
    src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function initialize() {
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);
    var myOptions = {
      zoom: 8,
      center: latlng,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
        myOptions);
```

So In FF it throws an error c[Db] is not a function
...Db](d);c.e=new Ff;c.Yb=new Mf;c.mapTypes=new Sf;c.features=new Af;var e=c.Zb=new...
How can I debug this error or fix?
  }

Comment: we need to see more code or a demo

Comment: function create_gmap(id, lat, lng, z){
 plog('GMAP START', 'MAPS');
 var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
 var myOptions = {
    zoom: 8,
    center: latlng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
 };
 var map = google.maps.Map(document.getElementById(id+'-canvas'), myOptions);

}

Comment: Is that code verbatim? Are you really using `set_to_true_or_false` or do you just have `true` or `false` as specified in the documentation? [Note: you can edit your question. You don't need to post comments which the interface will break]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've omitted the new-operator when creating the map, it has to be:

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById(id+'-canvas'), myOptions);
//________^
```